# Is it possible to change the focus using tab in vscode search palette?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to change the sugestions focus of the search (ctrl+p) or any command palette commands in vscode using tab, I tried lots of things but didn't get any exact command which solves my issue?

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0Aj9.png)

Want an keyboard shortcut json which helps to solve this

Comment: what do you mean by "change the focus"? you mean focus up and down between the list items?